# Image won't resize with these scripts

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, gsap

I am trying to implement a hover effect on an image with css and javascript and it works, but I cannot seem to resize the image! This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blonded</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <section class="gallery">
    <div class="imageContainer1">
    </div>

  </section>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./hover-effect.js"></script>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.imageContainer1 {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
#imageone {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
new hoverEffect ({
  parent: document.querySelector('.imageContainer1'),
  image1: 'img/bdcmag2.jpg',
  image2: 'img/bdcmag.jpg',
  displacementImage: 'img/displacement.jpg',
})
```

This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwlfy.png) of the code.

Comment: It's probably worth to mention which libs you're using as `new hoverEffect()` isn't native to JS

Comment: i added it to the bottom of my html file but it is Three.js and gsap.js. It's all from here: https://github.com/robin-dela/hover-effect - the ./hover-effect.js is also in the guide under 'hover-effect/dist/hover-effect.js '

Comment: You should add it as a tag to the question, so people familiar with those libs could see it

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You're not declaring the height for `.imageContainer1` anywhere. Just make it taller with `height`:

```
.imageContainer1 {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: still the same size :(